# Javascript: Using an "each" function as a callback on a "unique" function

Tags: javascript

I am working through an assignment to replicate parts of the underscore.js library.  I am stuck on implementing an "each" function into a "unique" function.

My each function is as follows:

```
_.each = function(collection, iterator) {
//checks to see if collection is an array or object
if (Array.isArray(collection)) {
  //if array, iterates an action function on each index value
  for (var i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
    iterator(collection[i], i, collection);
  }
}
//else statement takes care of an object passed as argument
  else {
    //for...in loop will iterate through object keys
    for (var key in collection) {
      iterator(collection[key], key, collection)
    }
  }       
}
```

I was able to use the above each function in a filter function as follows:

```
_.filter = function(collection, test) {       
     var newArray = [];
    //calling _.each function to iterate through array
    _.each(collection, function(value, index, list) {
    //applying truth test
      if (test(value, index, list)) {
      newArray.push(value);
      };
    });
  return newArray;
};
```

I am trying to use the each function in my "unique" function as follows:

```
_.uniq = function(array) {
    //two temporary arrays, one to hold unique values and one for duplicates
  var unique = [];
  var notUnique = [];
  _.each(array, function(item, index) {
    //sort array
    var sortedArray = array.sort(function(a, b){return a-b});
    //if value is not equal to the next value after sort, it goes to the unique array
    if (sortedArray[index] !== sortedArray[index+1]) {
      unique.push(sortedArray[index]);
    }
    //if the value matches the next value, it goes to the not unique array
    else {
      notUnique.push(sortedArray[index]);
    }
  return unique;
});
}
```

However when I run this on a test array, I receive a undefined output.  Will the array sort method not work when using a nested function like this?

Comment: Your return statement is one line too high.

Comment: Your title is misleading. You don't use `_.each` function as a **callback** in `_.uniq`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are returning `unique` array inside `_.each` so basically your `_.uniq` function retuning `undefined` by default.

```
_.uniq = function(array) {
    //two temporary arrays, one to hold unique values and one for duplicates
    var unique = [];
    var notUnique = [];
    _.each(array, function(item, index) {
        //sort array
        var sortedArray = array.sort(function(a, b) {
            return a - b
        });
        //if value is not equal to the next value after sort, it goes to the unique array
        if (sortedArray[index] !== sortedArray[index + 1]) {
            unique.push(sortedArray[index]);
        }
        //if the value matches the next value, it goes to the not unique array
        else {
            notUnique.push(sortedArray[index]);
        }
    });
    return unique;  // return here
}
```